# C#, EF, Multi-Level Inheritance, Data Won't Load

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm having a hard time retrieving data from a derived classes

In my example, I would like to pull data in a manner that the CoatRecipe has CoastSteps, and ScrubRecipes have ScrubSteps.

All the Steps have a collections of Outputs.

In this example, the Data is being saved, I can retrieve the Recipes, the Steps, but the Outputs will not get retrieved.  What am I missing?

I should add.  In this example. Recipe1.Steps does not have OutputList.  OutputList is what I would like to retrieve.

I'm using EntityFramework 6.1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] p)
        {
            DeleteData();
            CreateRecipes();
            using (var db = new DbModel())
            {
                var recipe1 = (from x in db.recipeDS.OfType<ScrubRecipe>()
                                  .Include(x => x.steps)
                               select x).FirstOrDefault();

                //var recipe2 = (from x in db.recipeDS.OfType<ScrubRecipe>()
                //                  .Include(x => x.steps.OfType<ScrubStep>().Select(y => y.outputList))
                //               select x).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        private static void DeleteData()
        {
            using (var db = new DbModel())
            {
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [StepOutputs]");
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [RecipeSteps]");
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Recipes]");
            }
        }

        private static void CreateRecipes()
        {
            // Output to be saved.
            var stepOutput = new StepOutput();

            // Create a Recipe
            var scrubRecipe = new ScrubRecipe
            { steps = { new ScrubStep { outputList = { stepOutput } } } };

            // Create a Recipe
            var coatRecipe = new CoatRecipe
            { steps = { new CoatStep { outputList = { stepOutput } } } };

            // Save the Recipes
            using (var db = new DbModel())
            {
                db.scrubRecipeDS.AddOrUpdate(scrubRecipe);
                db.coatRecipeDS.AddOrUpdate(coatRecipe);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public List<RecipeStep> steps { get; set; } = new List<RecipeStep>();
    }

    public class CoatRecipe : Recipe { }

    public class ScrubRecipe : Recipe { }

    public abstract class RecipeStep
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Recipe recipe { get; set; }
    }

    public class CoatStep : RecipeStep
    {
        public List<StepOutput> outputList { get; set; } = new List<StepOutput>();
    }

    public class StepOutput
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual RecipeStep recipeStep { get; set; }
    }

    public class ScrubStep : CoatStep
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    public class DbModel : DbContext
    {
        public DbModel()
            : base("name=DbModelConn")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DbModel>());
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Recipe> recipeDS { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RecipeStep> recipeStepDS { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StepOutput> stepOutputDS { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<ScrubRecipe> scrubRecipeDS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ScrubStep> scrubRecipeStepDS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CoatRecipe> coatRecipeDS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CoatStep> coatRecipeStepsDS { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ScrubStep>()
                .HasMany(x => x.outputList)
                .WithRequired(x => (ScrubStep)x.recipeStep);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean can't retrieve it? result is null?

Comment: The Outputs collection will not populate.  The Recipes and The Steps do.

Comment: If you place a break on the recipe, you'll see that the recipe was loaded, and the step as well.   I couldn't figure out a way to include the outputs, being that the step collection is form a base class.

Comment: In most cases I have run into with EF and inheritance, I have to use explicit loading to get any properties that are on the child classes but not on the parent classes. Explicit loading does not have the performance of eager loading (because it hits the database a lot more) but it will get the job done.

Comment: Matt, I tried to explicitly set a relationship between a ScrubStep and the outputList, but It didn't work.  I only posted my most reasonable attempt.  
If you notice the OnModelCreating() method, you'll see one of my many attempts.

Comment: Explicit loading isn't a Fluent API or Data Annotation setting. Explicit loading is done after the initial query. Check out this [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx) or the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework/4678/loading-related-entities/16447/explicit-loading#t=201701150156532881038) on SO.

Comment: in my example.  Recipe1.steps doesn't have outputList, How would I apply explicit loading to Recipe1 ?

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example of explicit loading that should work for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the parent class `RecipeStep` that does not contain the collection that you need, you will have to use [explicit loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx) to load the collection. You will also need to cast each `RecipeStep` to the child class that contains the collection.

```
foreach (var coatStep in recipe1.steps.OfType<CoatStep>())
{
    db.Entry(coatStep).Collection(x => x.outputList).Load();
}
```

The performance one this execution will not be the best because it causes a database query with each iteration. However, it really shouldn't be too bad unless you have an extraordinary amount of entities.

Comment: `steps` doesn't have `outputlist` property.

Comment: it won't let me include the outputList, being that the steps are of the base type, and not from the derived class, which is what I need.

Comment: This worked great with the CoatStep, but not with the ScrubStep.  I believe  what I'm encountering with the ScrubStep is a different problem.  More of a design issue.  I solved it by creating an intermediate class that holds the shared outputs.  

Thank you @Matt Rowland you have cured my eye from twitching like crazy.

Comment: If you want it to work with both you could either do it twice or use an interface that both `CoatStep` and `ScrubStep` implement. Using an interface would be the best route because the same single call could be used for both steps, and potentially new step types as well.